# Running a python script which takes an argument using Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

Let's say I have a python script located at `C:\script.py`. This is the contents of the script:

```
def func1(arg1):
    print (arg1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func1(arg1)
```

Now, I want to run this script using Robot Framework. I'm thinking about doing something like this:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    Run Process    python     C:\script.py ${arg1}
```

But it doesn't work. How can I run this script, and pass an argument to it?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Helio, making python program as a keyword will be faster and easy solution to implement.
Import py script in settings section under Library.

`${result}=    func1   arg1`

Here func1 act as a keyword to do whatever it is suppose to do as a function. Then result variable will capture the output which then can be logged or printed to console.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to modify your script to use command line arguments which you can find in [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

For example:

```py
import sys

def func1(arg1):
    print (arg1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func1(sys.argv[1])
```

Next, you must make sure to have two or more spaces between `script.py` and the argument:

```
Run Process    python     C:\\script.py  ${arg1}
```

And, of course, you need to define what `${arg1}` is, which you didn't do in your example.

Comment: @brian Thanks, but I don't have an ${arg2}! I only have an arg1, which I want to pass from RF to Python. Is it doable?

Comment: @tajir12457: I think you've missed the point of the answer. You have to supply an argument. You can put anything there. Your example showed `${arg1}` so that's what I used. You could just as easily do `Run Process  python  c:\\script.py  hello, world`

Answer (score 0):

It would be nicer if you have posted a real example that we could experiment, to understand:

> But it doesn't work.

As you can see in the documentation of [Run Process](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Run%20Process), you have to redirect the output of your process, so you can see it (if that was your problem).

Here is a working example based on yours:

```
import sys

arg1 = sys.argv[1] or None

def func1(argument):
    print(argument)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    func1(arg1)
```

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Process

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    Run Process    python    C:/script.py    This is my argument to script.    stdout=C:/script_output.log
```

But maybe the best solution is to make your script as a Keyword.

Comment: You don't _have_ to redirect the output. The `Run process` keyword returns an object which contains the stdout.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as this :
your python file, test.py

```
def printme(x, y):   
    with open("output.txt", "a") as f:        
        f.write("\n ===> " + x + " / " + y)
```

your robot file :

```
*** Settings ***
Library    test.py


*** Test Cases ***
Test        
    printme   Hello World   second argument
```

You get a file output.txt, with :

===> Hello World / second argument

Instead of a simple string, you can have variables, anything you want.
You can have several arguments, with at least two spaces between them.